# NginX: HTTPS connections refused

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I've created SSL sertificate using `Let's Encrypt` and now trying to setup it with NginX. The NginX consumes my config, restarts and handles HTTP well, but refuses HTTPS connection.

Also, my server has no firewall. I checked the port 443 with `netstat -peanut | grep ":443 "` and NMap, there is no problem with it.

I have the following SSL files:

1. `ca bundle.crt`, 27 lines, begins with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`
2. `ca.crt`, 35 lines, begins with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`
3. `private_rsa.key`, 27 lines, begins with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`
4. `private.key`, 28 lines, begins with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`

I don't know which ones are important, so I tried all the combinations, but nothing works. Here is my NginX config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  domain.ru www.domain.ru;

    ssl_certificate /var/www/SSL/ca.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/SSL/private.key;


    access_log  /var/www/Ret/Returner/logs/nginx.access.log;
    error_log  /var/www/Ret/Returner/logs/nginx.error.log;

    proxy_read_timeout 950s;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/Ret/Returner/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

How to fix the problem?

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04. NginX version: 1.10.3 built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g, TLS SNI support enabled.

**Update.**

To generate certificates I used 2 different approaches:

1. Using www.sslforfree.com with DNS ownership approval.
2. Using the following OpenSSL commands:

`openssl genrsa 4096 > /var/www/Ret/account.key`

`openssl rsa -in /var/www/Ret/account.key -pubout`

Unfortunately, both certificate file sets didn't work.

Comment: How have you generated SSL certificate? Could you update your question with a command you've run? The output of Let's Encrypt should output `fullchain.pem`, `privkey.pem`, and other files, but only those two are needed in most cases.

Comment: @dr.dimitru thanks for your reply! I have added these details to the Q. I used these ways coz found them most convenient.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @SaraTibbetts Yes, I've found the solution a long time ago! I've just written it for you  Hope, it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. It was about creation of `ca_chain.crt` which should contain data of your certificate and CA bundle. It's structure is simple, as follows:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFXTCCBEWgAwIBAgISA1jUznaa6AUn/4wyOV49e1QBMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
// content of the ca.crt //
2PxVU6WNy9wOVgGdO5TaxRQgO2p04AYJpovREYCuOctz
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEkjCCA3qgAwIBAgIQCgFBQgAAAVOFc2oLheynCDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA/
// content of the ca_bundle.crt //
KOqkqm57TH2H3eDJAkSnh6/DNFu0Qg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Then, in the NginX config:

```
ssl_certificate /aivanf/ssl/ca_chain.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /aivanf/ssl/ca.key;
```

The `ca.key` is the same as what I previously called `private.key`

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't like having 80 and 443 in the same `server` section.
I am also not sure if that's an issue. But could you try something like this?

```
# Redirect all http to https
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}

# Handle https
server {
    server_name domain.ru www.domain.ru;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    # Certificates
    ssl_certificate /var/www/SSL/ca.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/SSL/private.key;

    # Logs
    access_log  /var/www/Ret/Returner/logs/nginx.access.log;
    error_log  /var/www/Ret/Returner/logs/nginx.error.log;

    proxy_read_timeout 950s;

    # Static Content
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/Ret/Returner/;
    }

    # Reverse Proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've tried both your approach of separating ports and just disabling the listening 80, but result is the same: `verni-verni.ru unexpectedly closed the connection` (Google Chrome)